# Perl line/delimiter file formatting syntax

Tags: perl, syntax

I'm trying to figure out how to use a code that's written in perl, but am not very familiar with perl syntax. I was wondering if someone could tell me what the format of the file @metafilecache is? The code is failing to read the samplerate within the file, but I'm not sure how I have it formatted incorrectly. Here's the excerpt of the code I think is appropriate:

```
my $tnet = $ARGV[0];
my $tsta = $ARGV[1];
my $stadir = $ARGV[2]; 

if ( ! -d "$targetdir" ) {
  mkdir "$targetdir" || die "Cannot create $targetdir: $?\n";
}

die "Cannot find PDF bin base dir: $pdfbinbase\n" if ( ! -d "$pdfbinbase" );

my %targetdays = ();
my %targetchan = ();

# Collect target files in the $pdfbinbase dir, limited by $changlob
  foreach my $nsldir (glob("$pdfbinbase/{CHRYS}/$tnet.$tsta.*")) {
   next if ( ! -d "$nsldir" ); # Limit to directories

   # Extract location ID from directory name
   my ($net,$sta,$loc) = $nsldir =~ /\/(\w+)\.(\w+)\.([\w-]+)$/;

   if ( $net ne $tnet ) {
     print "Target network ($tnet) != network ($net)\n";
     next;
   }
   if ( $sta ne $tsta ) {
     print "Target station ($tsta) != station ($sta)\n";
     next;
   }

   foreach my $chandir (glob("$nsldir/$changlob")) {
     next if ( ! -d "$chandir" ); # Limit to directories

   # Extract channel code from directory name
     my ($chan) = $chandir =~ /.*\/([\w\d]+)$/;

     foreach my $yeardir (glob("$chandir/Y*")) {
       next if ( ! -d "$yeardir" ); # Limit to directories

       # Extract year from directory name
       my ($year) = $yeardir =~ /^.*\/Y(\d{4,4})$/;

       foreach my $daybin (glob("$yeardir/D*.bin")) {
         next if ( ! -f "$daybin" ); # Limit to regular files

         my ($day) = $daybin =~ /^.*\/D(\d{3,3})\.bin$/;

         $targetdays{"$loc.$chan.$year.$day"} = $daybin;
         $targetchan{"$loc.$chan"} = 1;
       }
     }
   }
 }
     if ( $verbose > 1 ) {
        print "Target days from PDF bin files:\n";
        my $count = 0;
        foreach my $tday (sort keys %targetdays) {
          print "Target day: $tday => $targetdays{$tday}\n";
          $count++;
        }
      print "Targets: $count\n";
     }

 # Remove targets that have already been calculated by checking
 # results files against targets.
 foreach my $tchan ( keys %targetchan ) {
   my ($loc,$chan) = split (/\./, $tchan);
   # Generate target file name
   my $targetfile = undef;
   if ( $loc ne "--" ) { $targetfile = "$targetdir/$prefix-$loc.$chan"; }
     else { $targetfile = "$targetdir/$prefix-$chan"; }

     print "\nChecking target file for previous results: $targetfile\n"  
     if        ( $verbose );

   next if ( ! -f "$targetfile" );

     # Open result file and remove any targets that are included
     open IN, "$targetfile" || next;
     foreach my $line (<IN>) {
       next if ( $line =~ /^YEAR\.DAY/ );
         my ($year,$day) = $line =~ /^(\d+).(\d+)/;

         # Delete this target
         delete $targetdays{"$loc.$chan.$year.$day"};
       }
   close IN;
  }

  if ( $verbose > 1 ) {
    print "Remaining target days:\n";
    my $count = 0;
    foreach my $tday (sort keys %targetdays) {
      print "Target day: $tday => $targetdays{$tday}\n";
      $count++;
    }
    print "Remaining Targets: $count\n";
  }
 my %targetfiles = ();

 # Calculate and store PDF mode for each target day
 TARGET: foreach my $tday (sort keys %targetdays) {
 my ($loc,$chan,$year,$day) = split (/\./, $tday);

 my %power = ();
 my %count = ();
 my @period = ();

 # Determine sampling rate
 my $samprate = GetSampRate ($tnet,$tsta,$loc,$chan);
 print "Samplerate for $tnet $tsta $loc $chan is: $samprate\n" if (     
 $verbose );
 if ( ! defined $samprate ) {
   if ( ($tsta eq "ECSD") || ($tsta eq "SFJ") || ($tsta eq "CASEE") ||     
     ($tsta eq "JSC") ){
     next;
   }
   else {
     print "Cannot determine sample rate for channel 
     $tnet.$tsta.$loc.$chan\n";
     next;
   }
 }
```

This is the subroutine GetSampRate:

```
sub GetSampRate {    # GetSampRate (net,sta,loc,chan)

  my $net  = shift;
  my $sta  = shift;
  my $loc  = shift;
  my $chan = shift;

  my $samprate = undef;

  # Generate source name: Net_Sta_Loc_Chan
  my $srcname = "${net}_${sta}_";
  $srcname   .= ($loc eq "--") ? "_" : "${loc}_";
  $srcname   .= "$chan";

  if ( $#metafilecache < 0 ) {

    my $metafile = "$stadir/metadata.txt";

    if ( ! -f "$metafile" ) {
      print "GetSampRate(): Cannot find metadata file: $metafile\n";
      return undef;
    }

    # Open metadata file
    if ( ! (open MF, "<$metafile") ) {
      print "GetSampRate(): Cannot open: $metafile\n";
      return undef;
    }

    # Read all lines in the metafilecache
    @metafilecache = <MF>;

    close MF;
  }

  # Read all lines starting with srcname into @lines
  my @lines = grep { /^$srcname/ } @metafilecache;

  # Find maximum of sample rates for this channel
  foreach my $line ( @lines ) {
    my @fields = split(/\t/, $line);
    my $rate   = $fields[7];

    $samprate = $rate if (!defined $samprate || $rate > $samprate);
  }

  return $samprate;
}
```

Comment: You're showing us a subroutine that should be called with 4 values (`GetSampRate (net,sta,loc,chan)`). Whether it works correctly or not will depend on the part of the script that sets the variables being passed to it. Find the lines that call `GetSampRate` and see where whatever is passed is being defined. We can't help based on what you show us.

Comment: There's only 1 line that calls this: my $samprate = GetSampRate ($tnet,$tsta,$loc,$chan). All of these variables are being defined. The error message states: Samplerate for XX CHRYS 00 BH1 is: 
Cannot determine sample rate for channel XX.CHRYS.00.BH1.

Comment: That error message is not printed by the code you show so, again, we can't help based on this code. You need to see how those 4 variables are set. Basically, you need to show us a full, reproducible example, showing both your input data and the entire program. We can do nothing with just a subroutine (especially since it isn't even the source of the error message).

Comment: $tnet and $tsta are set when the code is called and also stripped off the directory structure to ensure what's being called on the command line actually exists.  ./code.pl $tnet $tsta $targetdir. $loc and $chan are stripped off the directory structure. The code is really long, so I thought I wouldn't include it. I can show the basic setup and will edit the question.

Answer (score -1):

The code you have shown is very clunky.

- As far this scope is concerned, the file is called `$stadir/metadata.txt` and I can't help with `$stadir` as it's either undefined or a global value that is set elsewhere — not a great design idea
- After that, `@metafilecache = <MF>` loads the entire file into the array `@metafilecache`, leaving a trailing newline character at the end of each element
- Then `my @lines = grep { /^$srcname/ } @metafilecache` duplicates to `@lines` all lines beginning with the string held in `$srcname`. This is another global variable that shouldn't be used
- The following `for` loop splits the line on tab (`"\t"` or `"\x09"`) separators and sets `$rate` to the eighth value (`$fields[7]`). `$samprate` is updated at each iteration if the latest value of `$rate` is greater than the current stored maximum

I hope that helps

Comment: What is another global variable? `@lines` and `$srcname` are both declared in the sub. What am I missing?

Comment: @terdon: I was referring to `@metafilecache`. which is neither declared nor defined in the code that you show. You can pass arrays to subroutines by reference with only the tiniest overhead, and that is what you should do here

Comment: @Borodin, yes the file metatdata.txt file is stored in the /$stadir directory, that much I do know. I know I have the file in the correct location. Here $stadir would be CHRYS. The file is separated by tabs, but do you know what it puts in the elements 5-7? This is what I'm not certain about. Given the subroutine I believe the first four are $tnet, $tsta, $loc, $chan. But I couldn't figure out what's between the first 4 elements up to the samplerate. Or for that matter how the sample rate is supposed to be defined in the file.